# open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ property of diameter

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Problem:

Assume $W$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Assume $X$ is a metric space $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is continuous. Suppose $g:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{>0}$ is a continuou function such that $g(x)<d(f(x),\mathbb{R}^n\backslash W)$ for all $x\in X$.

Show that if $F$ is closed in $X$, then for each $x\in X\backslash F$, there exists an open set $U$ of $x$ contained in $X\backslash F$ such that $diameter(f(U))<\inf g(U)$

I'm not sure how to proof this.

My ideas: $F$ is closed so $X\backslash F$ is open. Assume for each open set $U$ of $x$ in $X\backslash F$, we have diameter$f(U)\geq \inf g(U)$

Case 1: Assume we have $>$. Then this means there exists $w_1,w_2\in U$ such that  $\inf g(U) < |f(w_1)-f(w_2)|$

So, $g(w_1)<d(f(w_1),\mathbb{R}^n\backslash W)$ and $g(w_2)<d(f(w_2),\mathbb{R}^n\backslash W)$

I am not sure what else to do

Comment: Is $g$ strictly positive? Or can it attain the value zero? Because, it implies that $f(X)\subseteq W$ if $g(z)>0$ for all $z\in X$.

Comment: Is there some more information regarding the relation between $F$ and $W$?

Comment: Ignore $F$, which is pretty much a red herring here. First show the case when $F = \varnothing$. I.e., that each $x \in X$ has a neighborhood with the property. And try proving this directly, instead of by contradiction.